# What is causing this "Corrupt `POSIXct` with unknown type logical" error in this dplyr cross join?

Tags: r, dplyr, cross-join

I have a data pipeline I wrote a while back, and for some reason (possibly with a new version of R or some packages) part of the script appeared to break. Specifically, I discovered a particular scenario where a cross-join with a 0-row data frame to another results in an error. I wish for the end result to also be a 0-row data frame with columns from both data frames (preserving their classes), but it results in an error that suggests it be reported to the package authors.

If there's something I am missing here to resolve this error, I would like to know.

For reference, I am using `dplyr 1.0.9` R `4.1.2` on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (more details shown at bottom) .

```
start_shifted <- structure(list(timestamp_start = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), timestamp_stop = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), time_since_last_stop = logical(0), 
    rest_time = numeric(0), ssid = integer(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")


lap_data <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(1509301003, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), start_time = "2017-10-29 12:59:00", 
    start_position_lat = 41.8741511832923, start_position_long = -87.620877083391, 
    end_position_lat = 41.8724051490426, end_position_long = -87.6218410022557, 
    total_elapsed_time = 55.003, total_timer_time = 55.003, total_distance = 221.85, 
    total_strides = 75L, total_calories = 11L, enhanced_avg_speed = 14.5188, 
    avg_speed = 14.5188, enhanced_max_speed = 15.6528, max_speed = 15.6528, 
    total_ascent = 0L, total_descent = 0L, event = "lap", event_type = "stop", 
    avg_heart_rate = 137L, max_heart_rate = 154L, avg_running_cadence = 82L, 
    max_running_cadence = 86L, lap_trigger = "session_end", sub_sport = "generic", 
    avg_fractional_cadence = 0.265625, max_fractional_cadence = 0.5, 
    total_fractional_cycles = NA, avg_vertical_oscillation = NA, 
    avg_temperature = NA, max_temperature = NA, timestamp_utc = "2017-10-29 18:16:43", 
    timezone = "America/Chicago", timestamp_previous = structure(NA, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), lap_id = 1L), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), class = "data.frame")

lap_data %>%
    inner_join(
      start_shifted,by=character()
    )
```

This is the error text:

```
Error in `datetime_validate()`:
! Corrupt `POSIXct` with unknown type logical.
ℹ In file type-date-time.c at line 387.
ℹ Install the winch package to get additional debugging info the next time you get this error.
ℹ This is an internal error in the rlang package, please report it to the package authors.
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─lap_data %>% mutate(dummy = TRUE) %>% ...
  2. ├─dplyr::inner_join(...)
  3. ├─dplyr:::inner_join.data.frame(...)
  4. │ └─dplyr:::join_mutate(...)
  5. │   ├─tibble::as_tibble(x, .name_repair = "minimal")
  6. │   └─tibble:::as_tibble.data.frame(x, .name_repair = "minimal")
  7. │     └─tibble:::lst_to_tibble(unclass(x), .rows, .name_repair)
  8. │       └─tibble:::check_valid_cols(x)
  9. │         ├─base::which(!map_lgl(x, is_valid_col))
 10. │         └─tibble:::map_lgl(x, is_valid_col)
 11. │           └─tibble:::map_mold(.x, .f, logical(1), ...)
 12. │             └─base::vapply(.x, .f, .mold, ..., USE.NAMES = FALSE)
 13. │               └─tibble FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 14. │                 └─vctrs::vec_is(x)
 15. │                   └─vctrs:::vec_is_vector(x)
 16. │                     └─vctrs `<fn>`()
 17. │                       └─vctrs::vec_proxy(x = x)
 18. │                         └─vctrs:::datetime_validate(x)
 19. └─rlang:::stop_internal_c_lib(...)
 20.   └─rlang::abort(message, call = call, .internal = TRUE)
```

More specific platform details:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the premise of a cross-join where one of the columns has zero rows.

Comment: It is part of a pipeline where there is usually, but not always, at least 1 row in the frame that has 0 rows here. Eventually additional filters based on inequalities would be run, but that's not where the error is being encountered or relevant here. For consistency's sake, I'd like to avoid having 2 different implementations, and it is possible to cross-join a tibble/data frame with a 0-row one. Just not the one I have here in this particular configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution so much as a clear identification of the problem.

If we iterate over each of the columns, such as

```r
inner_join(lap_data       , start_shifted, by = character()) # fails
inner_join(lap_data[,1:10], start_shifted, by = character()) # succeeds
inner_join(lap_data[,1:20], start_shifted, by = character()) # succeeds
```

We'll eventually determine that `timestamp_previous` (column 34) is the problem column. It's `NA` and has an empty `"tzone"`, let's see which of these is the problem.

```r
### refresh lap_data
lap_data[[34]] <- Sys.time()
inner_join(lap_data, start_shifted, by = character()) # succeeds
```

So it isn't a problem with `POSIXt` per se. Let's look at the different types of `NA` (starting with a fresh version of `lap_data` with each assignment/test). Bottom line, each of these succeeds the `inner_join(..)`.

```r
### refresh lap_data
# logical NA
lap_data[[34]] <- NA # inner_join(lap_data, start_shifted, by = character()) succeeds
lap_data[[34]] <- NA_real_
lap_data[[34]] <- NA_character_
lap_data[[34]] <- Sys.time()[NA]
```

All succeed. It's the last one that's a little odd to me, since the original `timestamp_previous` is also `POSIXt` and `NA`, so ...

```r
dput(Sys.time()[NA])
# structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
dput(lap_data[[34]])
# structure(NA, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

The key here took a long time for me to find, but ... *your* `timestamp_previous` has the `logical` variant of `NA` in it, which should not be. However you are getting/converting/creating that field has a flaw in it.

To clarify what we have (first) with what we need (second):

```r
dput(lap_data[[34]])
# structure(NA, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
dput(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(lap_data[[34]])))
# structure(NA_real_, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

Further, if we strip the `class=` from the structures,

```r
class(unclass(lap_data[[34]]))
# [1] "logical"
class(unclass(Sys.time()))
# [1] "numeric"
```

The resolution to this journey:

1. Fix the code. There is some code somewhere that is "corrupting" your `POSIXt` columns to be logical-`NA` with `class(..) <- c("POSIXct","POSIXt")`, whether literally or hidden. Fix that first.
2. For a quick fix of *this* data, here's a fix for *that one column*:

   ```r
   lap_data[[34]] <- as.POSIXct(unclass(lap_data[[34]]))
   inner_join(lap_data, start_shifted, by = character()) # succeeds
   ```

   And here's a fix if you have multiple columns:

   ```r
   fixpsx <- function(x, origin = "1970-01-01", tzone = "") {
     if (inherits(x, "POSIXt") && inherits(unclass(x), "logical")) 
       as.POSIXct(unclass(x), origin = origin, tzone = tzone)
     else x
   }
   lap_data[] <- lapply(lap_data, fixpsx)
   inner_join(lap_data, start_shifted, by = character()) # succeeds
   ```